# Souce code of a web text app?

Tags: android

Hey,
I'm trying to get the source code of an app similar to the two below in order to help with my Final Year Project in college. I can't seem to find a way of getting the source code for the two I've mentioned below, so does anyone know of any others that interact with the web texts sights for which the code would be available? Thanks

Irish Cabbage Light:https://market.android.com/details?id=com.cabbagetexter.android.cabbage&feature=search_result
or
Textdroid: http://www.appbrain.com/app/textdroid/com.app.android.textdroid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are commercial applications. They aren't going to hand out the source code for free.